# Why do we have to prove that we will return to our home country to receive a visa?

Tags: visas, customs-and-immigration

One of the conditions for Visa approval is to prove that we will return to our country by "Strong Family, Social or Economic Tie"?

What if I don't want to return? why do I have to return?

Why I can't choose where to live? isn't that a basic human right?

Comment: The evolution of the nation-state is long, but I suspect that the ability to live wherever one pleased ended very early in the development of cities. It's not recognized as a human right. One could try for asylum...

Comment: VTC because it is primarily opinion-based plus it's about moving long-term and nit traveling.

Comment: @fk not really, yes they want to move, but the question is 'why do we have to prove that we wil lreturn' which is a perfectly valid travel question.

Comment: This question is probably better suited to [Politics StackExchange](https://politics.stackexchange.com) than to this forum.

Comment: @fkraiem I updated the question, if you find any rants in it now, please let me know.

Comment: @fkraiem and which part is exactly opinion based?!! Question is "Why" and has a solid answer, how can it be opinion based if it's about "Why Have to"?

Comment: In all honesty, I think this is a good, non-opinionated question.

Comment: That's only a condition for a **visitor** visa - that you are in fact only visiting. There are ways to apply to move to a country. Some countries are stricter than others about who they allow to move in, but if you want to move, it doesn't start with pretending you just want to visit.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on Politics SE.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Wouldn't open borders be nice? :)

Unfortunately, political decisions by people in power also have control over this.

As a result, most countries set rules on who they 'allow' to move in.  So, they want to make sure you're going to leave again if they let you in.

For example:

- many countries don't want people with a criminal conviction coming in
- many want only educated, younger people coming in
- some countries limit because they may have fantastic social welfare, and don't want people coming in to just get paid for free
- some have historical issues with other citizens of countries, eg post war
- and more

The EU has helped with this in Europe at least, allowing some more freedom of movement.  Efforts are underway in Oceania and Latin America to reduce the barriers too.

If you're truly interested in moving, however, it'd be worth looking at [Expats](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/) for advice on how to do so.  Try and include all relevant info though, such as destination country, your citizenship and so on.

(disclaimer: I've tried to remain neutral on the reasons above, I'm not saying I disagree/agree with any of them)

Comment: About the part you said "get paid for free" or "people with a criminal conviction", I agree with that policy. but at least it would be better if there was a sort of statement form or something in which we could sign an agreement that we do not want any services from the host country and we accept all the consequences, it's our own life we have the right to decide for ourselves. but that's my opinion in a perfect world, who listens?